# Tag clean up request - [displaying]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, clean-up

I came across the [displaying](/questions/tagged/displaying) tag today and I can't see a real use for it.

There are some 250+ questions using the tag so any assistance in removing it would be most welcome.

As always with tag clean-ups don't just remove the offending tag. Take some time to clean up the rest of the question and even add some more appropriate tags if necessary.

Comment: I have cleaned up a few of these now. Why do so many people who use this tag also not know how to use a comma? Every single one I have cleaned up has but the comma after the space not before... For what languages is that the standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [displaying](/questions/tagged/displaying) tag is now orphan on Stack Overflow.

Just need to wait a bit for the great Orphan Tag Reaper to reclaim it.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks to all who helped.